# Putting average function in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have wanted to displays the employee number,  last name, and salary of all employees who earn more than the average salary and sort the results in order of ascending salary. However, i have been getting error 'group function is not allow here'. How should i write it?

```
select employee_id,last_name,salary from employees 
where salary > avg(salary)
order by salary;
```

Answer (score 2):

use `AVG() OVER()` Window aggregate function

```
select * from
(
select employee_id,last_name,salary,avg(salary)over() as avg_salary from employees 
) e
where salary > avg_salary 
order by salary;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.employee_id,a.last_name,a.salary from employees a 
where a.salary > (select avg(b.salary) from employees b) 
order by a.salary;
```

Comment: Don't we need () around the subquery?  I just submitted an edit, @luisteijon.